# trigger Lambda function when uploading to S3 then wait for its response, and return its response to the user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, puppeteer

Is this possible? I've seen [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) tutorial from AWS Lambda wherein S3 can trigger it but what I want to do is return that function's response to the user.

To provide context, this is what I want to achieve:
Upload HTML files to S3, trigger a Lambda function that converts it to PDF (using Puppeteer) then return the links to the converted file back to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. There is no concept of "returning back to the user".

If you have an application that uploads the object to Amazon S3 (eg a mobile app, or a web app), it could check for a converted file and show it to the user, but this would be **the responsibility of your application**. It is not a capability of Amazon S3 nor AWS Lambda.

Comment: i think we can do it.have to do some extra hard work to write the node function in lambda.

Comment: When the file upload to Amazon S3 completes, the upload operation ends. Amazon S3 triggers the Lambda function, but there is no connection between the Lambda function and the user's original upload operation. Therefore, the Lambda function cannot "return" anything to the user performing the upload.

Comment: got it you are absolutely right. but if we manage to get file name that is uploaded we can modify or perform the operation on it.  String key = event.getRecords().get(0).getS3().getObject().getKey();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43467558/how-to-get-recently-uploaded-zip-file-from-s3-bucket-when-we-trigger-the-lambda

Comment: Certainly! The Amazon S3 trigger will pass the Bucket and Key to the Lambda function so that it can perform operations on the object, such as converting to a PDF. It simply can't "return the links to the converted file back to the user".

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. With this, I'll probably just have to check the bucket for my file every n seconds. @JohnRotenstein, will my Lambda function get called n times if I have n number of files? Or will it get called only once? This is because i'll have to upload three files to be exact. Head, body and footer.

Comment: I believe that each object that is created will trigger a separate Amazon S3 event. However, the `event` contains a list of `Records`, so create a loop to handle the possibility of receiving more than one object.